# Replace function of pandas does not seem to work

Tags: django, pandas, django-views

I looked around but I couldn't find something that could help me. I have a dataset which is composed like this:

```
rsid name  countexperiments
7  18                  1
8  448                 1
```

this dataset is later converted in a dataframe and then I call the replace function

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'a.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df.replace(7, 5, inplace=True)
```

but after that the output is still

```
rsid name  countexperiments
7  18                  1
8  448                 1
```

Comment: did you also try `df.replace(7, 5,regex=True, inplace=True)` ?

Comment: The value is quite likely stored as a string. You can convert it like this: `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)`, or you could specify the column types in the `pd.read_csv` call...

Comment: Check the data type of each column in your frame: `df.dtypes`. If `rsid` says `object`, the column is string, not integer

Comment: thanks to all of now it works